# Derivative of an analytic function at a point in the domain

Tags: complex-analysis

If the function $f(z)$ is analytic and one valued in $|z-a|<R$.

Prove that for $0<r<R$, $\displaystyle f'(a)=\frac{1}{\pi r}\int_{0}^{2\pi}P(\theta)e^{-i\theta}d\theta$

Where $P(\theta)$ is the real part of $f(a+re^{i\theta})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g (z) = f (z ) + \overline {f (a+\dfrac{r^2}{\bar{z}-\bar{a}})} $.

Note that $\displaystyle\int_{|z|=r} \dfrac{g (z)}{(z-a)^2}dz = \int_{|z|=r} \dfrac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}dz$. The integral on the LHS is well defined as the circle at $ a $ of radius $ r $ is contained in the domain of $ g $ (which is given by the annulus $\dfrac{r^2}{R} < |z-a| < R$).

Convert the contour integral on the LHS using the paramerization $ z=a+re^{i\theta}$. You should recognize the integral on the RHS.

After a few symbolic manipulations you will arrive at the desired expression.

Let me know if you want further hints.

Comment: How do I get the real part of the function to come into the expression?

Comment: Have you tried substituting $z=a+re^{i\theta}$ into $g(z)$? Once you do that, you will see.

Comment: Yes, I got it now. I could not understand how you wrote $\displaystyle\int_{|z|=r} \dfrac{g (z)}{(z-a)^2}dz = \int_{|z|=r} \dfrac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}dz$

Comment: Write the Taylor series expansion for $f$ in $|z-a|<R$. This will give you a Laurent series expansion for $g$ in $\dfrac{r^2}{R} <|z-a|<R$. Term by term integration shows that all the terms introduced by the conjugate of $f$ vanish.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. By Cauchy Integral formula
\begin{align}
f'(a)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)\,dz}{(z-a)^2}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}
f\big(a+r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}\big)\frac{1}{r^2\mathrm{e}^{2i\vartheta}}ri\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}d\vartheta\\ &=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_0^{2\pi}
f\big(a+r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}\big)\mathrm{e}^{-i\vartheta}d\vartheta.
\end{align}

Comment: What about the real part of the function which is there in the problem statement?